# Parse file names in directory to output to csv with timestamp?

Tags: powershell

I have several hundred documents inside of a few directories.  All have a common naming structure but the values differ:

```
10_03022014_229_14_12-9663 5930 4454.pdf

10_03022014_230_19_4-574 1564 1452 177.pdf
```

What I am attempting to do is create a CSV based upon this data, strip some whitespace, and remove the PDF filename extension in PowerShell.  The end result would look something like this:

```
10,03022014,229,14,12,966359304454

10,03022014,230,19,4,57415641452177
```

All of these values are alpha-numeric except for the final one which is barcode data.

To further complicate things for myself I need to have the output file have a similar naming structure based upon the first two "values" followed by a date and time stamp.

Example would be `10_03022014_datestamp_timestamp.csv` if the files in the directory start with `10_02022014`.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is not working? Are all the files in the directory using the same first two "values" which you use in the csv file name?  Also, could you clarify what formatting `datestamp_timestamp` should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name processing seems straightforward enough. I believe you're just replacing underscores, hyphens with a comma and removing spaces from the file's base name.  The following should get you the reformatted strings, at least per your two provided values:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.pdf' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName -Replace '[-_]', ',' -Replace ' ', '' }
```

I'm still not exactly clear on what you mean about the csv file name.  Once you clarify that, I'd be happy to help with that as well.

---

I think this is closer to what you're looking to do:

```
# Generate '_date_time.csv' string.
$fileSuffix = "_" + (Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd) + "_" + (Get-Date -Format HHmm) + ".csv"

Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.pdf' |
    ForEach-Object {
        # Get the first two tokens, underscore delimited, of PDF file name.
        $filePrefix = $_.Name.Split('_')[0,1] -Join('_')
        # Preform requisite replacements on PDF file name
        $string = $_.BaseName -Replace '[-_]', ',' -Replace ' ', ''
        # Write string out to CSV file, concat prefix/suffix to generate name.
        $string | Out-File -Append -FilePath $($filePrefix + $fileSuffix)
    }
```

Comment: This cleared up formatting so I can at least get a basic text file using Out-File now.  Thank you! I am horrible with scripting. To answer your questions: When I run this script I want it to create a new csv file each time.  Additionally I want the name of it based off of the other files within the folder since the first two "sections" are consistent.  An example is if all of the pdf files start with 10_03022014 for a specific directory.. I want to have the new csv file named 10_03022014.csv.  Then taking it one step forward adding a date and time stamp to it like: 10_03022014_date_time.csv

Comment: I've added an edit which dumps the values to a CSV named (I think) as you're asking.  You'll need to adjust the formatting of the '_date_time' portion as needed -- you didn't clarify the specifics.

Comment: Replace `$_.Name` with `$_.BaseName` to get the filename without extension.

Comment: You nailed it.  Once I have the rest done I will post it all back.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks @Graimer! I've added in your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution:

```
#Get pdf-files
Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pdf" |
#Group files that belong to the same csv-file
Group-Object -Property @{e={$_.BaseName.Split("_")[0,1] -join ("_")}} |
#Foreach csv-group
ForEach-Object {
    #Generate csv-filename
    $path = "$($_.Name)_$((Get-Date).ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmm")).csv"
    #Format content and save
    $_.Group | % { $_.BaseName -replace " " -replace '[-_]',"," } | Set-Content -Path $path
}
```

Comment: +1, but shouldn't `-Filter "*.txt"` be `-Filter "*.pdf"`?  I cannot get your example to work as is.

Comment: left-overs from testing. fixed now :)  you'll have to colaborate for me to be able to help. it works fine here in PowerShell 2.0 and up. what is not working? any errors?

Comment: It worked when I swapped `*.txt` and `*.pdf`, hence my +1 and comment. I particularly like your use of `Group-Object`, I'd not thought of that, cheers.

Comment: In my head, answers here on SO are not to be used as-is. They're general samples to get you going. :-) Both questions and answers should not be too specific.